# Error: is.character(from) while executing mapdist under ggmap in R module

Tags: r

i'm able to execute the below query properly-

```
> mapdist("newyork", "las vegas, nevada")

      from            to       m       km    miles seconds  minutes    hours
1 newyork las vegas, nevada 4059059 4059.059 2522.299  130967 2182.783 36.37972
```

but when I upload the below file named "Cities.CSV" I dont get the desired result-

```
  Org_city          Dest_city
New york        Las vegas, nevada
Washington DC       California
Pittsburg       Kansas City


> city = read.csv("cities.csv")
> dist = mapdist(cities$Org_city, Dest_city)
```

the error I get is -

```
Error: is.character(from) is not TRUE
```

I've installed all the required packages in R. Please help me with this.

Comment: I don't know the package but you could try it with `city = read.csv("cities.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus This definitely helps. Found the package and got it to work fully.

Comment: @docendodiscimus thanks buddy! Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

1) You save the contents from `read.csv` to a variable `city` but you reference a variable `cities` in your command.

2) You need to to do the same for the `to` city.

This should work, change `sep` to match your file, this assumes tab.

```
cities <- read.csv("cities.csv",sep="\t",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data.frame(t(sapply(1:nrow(cities),
    function(x) mapdist(cities$Org_city[x],cities$Dest_city[x]))))

           from                to       m       km    miles seconds  minutes    hours
1      New york Las vegas, nevada 4059059 4059.059 2522.299  130967 2182.783 36.37972
2 Washington DC        California 4497903 4497.903 2794.997  146008 2433.467 40.55778
3     Pittsburg       Kansas City 1353746 1353.746 841.2178   45116 751.9333 12.53222
```